# Getting reference to form with no id or name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project where I need to recall the fields entered in a form so I can repopulate them later.  When a form has a name, I can remember it and then later use some JavaScript (document.getElementsByName(...)[0]) to access it.  However, if there is no name...I'm at a loss for how to get a reference to it later.

I'm using jQuery, but am open to a JavaScript solution as well.  One idea is to remember the index of the form.  So, if it was document.forms[3] then later I can use the index.  However, when someone submits a form, how do I know the index of the form that it is? (NOTE: I am blindly adding submit handlers to all forms when a page loads to capture the activity.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of attaching events to the submit buttons, attach it to the `<form>` elements directly, like this:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  //do something with this
  //this == the form element being submitted
});
```

Or...in your current event handlers, use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the closest parent `<form>` element:

```
$(":submit").click(function() {
  var form = $(this).closest("form");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use an index on all `form` (flaky because someone may add a form in anywhere), you could use its surroundings as a reference... for example.

```
$('#content').parent().next().find('form')
```